# Getting Float Value Between 0 and 1

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am struggling to get a value between 0 and 1 based upon a percentage i.e 50% would show 0.5. The problem is that I am using the following and it always seems to return 0 for both values.

Even with the xPosition and yPosition set as 50% I still get 0;

```
float x_point = (1 / 100) * xPosition;
float y_point = (1 / 100) * yPosition;
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, the 50% represents an `xPosition` and `yPosition` of 0.5, correct?

Comment: Basically xPosition with be a value between 0 and 100 (percentage) so if the above is for example (1 / 100) * 50 I should get 0.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`1 / 100` is an integer expression which is equal to `0`, so `(1 / 100) * xPosition` will always be `0`.

You could change:

```
float x_point = (1 / 100) * xPosition;
```

to:

```
float x_point = (1.0 / 100.0) * xPosition;
```

or perhaps more simply:

```
float x_point = 0.01 * xPosition;
```

This will then be evaluated using floating point arithmetic and give the required result.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this can be simplified further to `x_point = xPosition / 100.0`

Comment: @max_ `xPosition * 0.01` would be preferable for the processor :D (If you're interested in saving a couple of nano seconds :D)

Comment: @Fogmeister that too ;)

Answer (score 1):

@PaulR's answer is awesome, however if you get those numbers (1 / 100) runtime, you may like to do,

```
NSInteger xPosition = 50;
NSInteger yPosition = 40;

float number = 1; //or set runtime
float divider = 100; //or set runtime

float x_point = (number / divider) * xPosition;
float y_point = (number / divider) * yPosition;

NSLog(@"x_point = %.f | y_point = %.f",x_point,y_point);
```

> Output : x_point = 0.5 | y_point = 0.4